# video play from url for a seconds only and crash on android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a video URL. when I try to play video using any of view(videoView, MediaPlayer, WebView) it plays for a second only and always crash. I checked video information and it is as

`Stream 0:
    Type: Video
    Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
    Resolution: 856x368
    Frame rate: 23.976000
    Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV`

`Stream 1
    Type: Audio
    Code: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
    Channels: Stereo
    Sample rate: 44100 Hz`

So, please tell me what is the problem in playing video, I am stuck here, and tried a lot of search but could not success.